# MIPS Development Environment

Tags: assembly, development-environment, mips

I am going to write a code in MIPS and looking for a software to give me some feature for debugging. Anyone knows a good software ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [MARS (MIPS Assembler and Runtime Simulator)](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/).

Comment: looks like what I was looking for,